# Network Extension capability missing in dev portal

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have two problems when compiling and installing an application on my iOS device.

Below are the details of the situation I find myself in.

I have an education licence (I work for a University); I log in to my developer.apple.com account, create my developer certificate, create an identity with the necessary capabilities, add the devices I need, and make a profile with all this information.

If I log in from Xcode (14 beta 6) and try to retrieve the profile automatically, I get this error: "The data couldn't be read because it is missing", and below the Try Again button, another error says: No profile for my.app.id was found. Unchecking "Automatically manage signing" and downloading the profile file from the developer portal, everything works: the code is compiled and signed, and a simple hello world app is correctly installed on my iPhone. So there is some problem downloading profiles from the developer portal. Why is this happening?

Apart from this problem (which can be overcome in some way), I cannot install the Wireguard app on my device from its source (https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-apple).

If I use the simulator as a target, the code compiles correctly, and the app is installed on the simulator.

However, when I try to install the app on my device, after manually loading the profile, I get that the Wireguard app does not compile because a capability is missing. More precisely, the errors are as follows:

- Provisioning profile "myapp" doesn't support the Network Extensions capability
- Provisioning profile "myapp" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension entitlement

The developer.apple.com portal does not have the Network Extension capability, so I don't know how to add it.

I have tried removing the Network Extension capability from the app configuration and using the Private VPN capability instead. The result is that the app is compiled and installed correctly, but when I try opening the vpn, the following logs come out:

```
2022-09-07 17:21:50.072024+0200 WireGuard[35390:2672224] [] Failed to save configuration docks-2: Error Domain=NEConfigurationErrorDomain Code=10 "permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=permission denied}
```

```
2022-09-07 17:21:50.072167+0200 WireGuard[35390:2671981] [] Failed to save configuration: Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=5 "permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=permission denied}
```

```
2022-09-07 17:21:50.072783+0200 WireGuard[35390:2671981] Add: Saving configuration failed: Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=5 "permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=permission denied}
```

I assume that these logs are due to the lack of the Network Extension capability that Wireguard is using.

Is the lack of this capability on the portal due to the education licence? Or is there an alternative way to solve this problem?

Thank you